# Multiple Flip Boxes - But only flip the one clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

my challenge is that I have two rows of boxes that I want to flip independently. Can't use hover as that is too chaotic, visually, for some users. So I have a JQuery script that toggles between classes, BUT, when applied to multiple boxes I get all of the boxes turning at once. I'd like to be able to turn over only the one clicked on like the hover effect. I can get that to happen if I give each box a separate class but that is a lot of extra CSS and I know that there has to be a better, cleaner way. Please help. :)

Here is the jquery code: $('.card') is what I'd like to use instead of ('cardOne', '.cardTwo', etc.)

```
function flip() {
        $('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    }
```

And here is the CSS (it's too cumbersome):

```
.container {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   -webkit-perspective: 800px;
   -moz-perspective: 800px;
   -o-perspective: 800px;
   perspective: 800px;
}
.cardOne, .cardTwo, .cardThree, .cardFour, .cardFive, .cardSix,    .cardSeven, .cardEight  {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
-o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
transition: transform 1s;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.cardOne div {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   /*line-height: 200px;*/
   color: #000;
   text-align: center;
   /*font-weight: bold;*/
   font-size: 18px;
   position: absolute;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cardOne .front, .cardTwo .front, .cardThree .front, .cardFour .front, .cardFive .front, .cardSix .front, .cardSeven .front, .cardEight .front {
   background: #9ddae5;
   line-height: 180px;
}
.cardOne .back, .cardTwo .back, .cardThree .back, .cardFour .back, .cardFive .back, .cardSix .back, .cardSeven .back, .cardEight .back {
   background: blue;
   line-height: 18px;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   -moz-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   -o-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   transform: rotateX( -180deg );
}
.cardOne.flipped, .cardTwo.flipped, .cardThree.flipped, .cardFour.flipped, .cardFive.flipped, .cardSix.flipped, .cardSeven.flipped, .cardEight.flipped {
   -webkit-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   -moz-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   -o-transform: rotateX( -180deg );
   transform: rotateX( -180deg );
}
```

And then, of course, the HTML (but I'll cut it to two boxes):

```
<div class="container">                
            <div class="cardOne" onclick="flipOne()">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <p>anxiety</p>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <!-- back content -->                        
                    <p>Occasional anxiety is a normal part of life. You might feel anxious when faced with a problem at work, before taking a test, or making an important decision. But anxiety disorders involve more than temporary worry or fear.  </p>

                </div>
            </div><!-- end flipper -->

        </div>
    </div> <!-- end col-1 -->

    <div class="col-1">   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="cardTwo" onclick="flipTwo()">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <p>infertility</p>
                    </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <!-- back content -->
                    <p>Grief is a real part of infertility. It may be heightened in miscarriages or stillbirths, but it is just as real when a couple cannot conceive.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end col-1 -->
```

Comment: `$('.card')` is looking for elements with a class, globally.  So that could match multiple elements.  But I don't even see that class in your markup, and I don't see you calling that method any where.

Comment: my bad. I changed it on the other page.The classes for each card was just '.card' but I switched them to 'cardOne, cardTwo, etc.' to get it to work independently. I would really like a script that uses just one class. Can't it be done with a loop or switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.card', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Using this logic, we bind with the script an event handler to the parent container of the cards.  Any time a card is clicked, it will toggle the flipped class on the card that was clicked.

```js
$('.container').on('click', '.card', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

```css
.card {
 display: inline-block;
 min-width: 100px;
 min-height: 80px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.card.flipped { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Taplar , I will try that.

Comment: It's not working. Taplar. I must be doing something wrong. I've added what you offered into a function of it's own 'flip' and put that with an onclick event in the html and nothing is happening now.

Comment: No, you don't do any onclick in the html.  This logic creates the click bindings, itself.  You should be able to literally take the javascript in the answer and use it as is.  As you can see from the snippet, there is no inline onclick binding.  It is not needed, and not using inline bindings and separating your markup from your javascript logic is the preferred practice.

Comment: Good deal.  Glad you got it figured out, :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.card').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
}
```

And you'll only need one class `.card` reducing writng and so on.

*Ps: remove the function declation and replaced it with the code above and remove all `onclick="flip()"` from your `HTML`.*